# Powershell 4 Write-Progress

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to run an IP check from a loooong list of.. well, IPs.. with [System.Net.DNS]
This works great, however I want to put a simple progress bar on it. Be it seconds or Percentage... Don't really care. I just want a nice progress bar to show up and tell me how long I need to wait.

```
$colComputers = get-content $File
foreach ($strComputer in $colComputers)
{
$IP = try {$dnsresult = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($strComputer)} `
catch {$dnsresult = "Fail"}
$IP

for ($IP=100; $IP -gt 1; $IP--) {
  Write-Progress -Activity "Working..." `
   -SecondsRemaining $IP `
   -Status "Please wait."
}
```

Script runs great, just getting stuck on this progress bar.
I was thinking it would be nice if at all possible to determine how many IPs the list contains and just let it count down from last to first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding your script.

- What is `$IP = try { }`?
- You output `$IP` (which I though would always be null), why?.
- You never use `$dnsresult` ..
- I'm not even sure how that progressbar is going to help anyone.....
- You really need make your code more readable. Avoid "escaping linebreaks".

Is this what you were trying to do?

```
$colComputers = @(get-content $File)
$count = $colComputers.Count
$i = 1
foreach ($strComputer in $colComputers)
{

    #Write-Progress needs -percentagecomplete to make the progressbar move
    Write-Progress -Activity "Working... ($i/$count)" -PercentComplete ($i/$colComputers.Count*100) -Status "Please wait."

    #What is IP = try { } :S
    try {
        $dnsresult = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($strComputer)
    }
    catch {
        $dnsresult = "Fail"
    }

    #Do something with $dnsresults...

    #Increase counter i
    $i++

}
```

Comment: Well i altered the script in hope to get the progress bar to work.. :-)

With your altering, it worked like a charm, thanks a lot man!

My post got edited but it clearly stated i am a newb with progress bars :-P